# Digital delay decay

Tags: delay

I am developing a digital delay on a microcontroller and I am stuck with the delay decay. The delay is implemented with a comb filter.

Here it is: http://www.tonmeister.ca/main/textbook/intro_to_sound_recording837x.png

The delay line, "emulating the tape", is implemented as a circula buffer. The effect can be killed and such case does not represents an issue; when turning the effect off though, I have the tail of the delay left in the buffer to process, as if the delay had been frozen and the tail slowly decay (depending on the feedback gain).

> My question is: how many times I have to recirculate samples through the buffer?

One way I thought to approach this could be by modelling the physical process ... assuming that the input sequence has a loudness of 0dB for its entire duration and that, after going through the delay line, it gets attenuated by a factor of 1/10. In terms of loudness this corresponds to a drop of 20dB, as power = voltage^2, every time the sequence goes through the feedback path. The weakest audible sound has a loudness of −130dB but, taking into consideration the ambient noise as well, −120dB will be sufficient as the least reference power. Hence, after the echoes have been through the feedback path 6 times (120dB/20dB) they will be no longer audible.

> Is there a more efficient way?

Thank you!